# How to use text from a block view as a prefix to a node title

Tags: 7, views, theming

> What I would like to do

In Durpal 7, I am using a block view to display our manufacturers name above our node titles. We added a custom region above content, and that is working fine. However, I would like the manufacturer to be display **inline** with the node title.

> How I handled it in Drupal 8

In [this related question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/288525/how-to-add-a-referenced-taxonomy-term-name-to-the-node-title-in-page-title-html/288680#288680) I asked about a Drupal 8 solution.The drupal 8 solution was a little simpler in that we migrated all manufacturer fields into 1 manufacturer field. which made things much easier to code. In my drupal 7 site, the manufacturer fields are separate making it a little messier to handle with code in that there would need to be an instance of the code for every manufacturer/node combo.

> My question

For drupal 7 is it possible to render a **block view** as an inline prefix to a node title? Placing a block view in this circumstance seems like it would be a much simpler and more front end Drupal approach. Especially since I can have all of the manufacturer fields in the one block view, and they will render according to Taxonomy term ID contextual filter.

Comment: Is it about inline as in you can do that with CSS maybe? Then maybe have a custom block that gets the current node, gets the title and returns it? And then place that block next to manufacturer block and display them inline with just CSS?

Comment: That would be fine but I would have to remove the default drupal node title from the template then?

Comment: Actually that could be accomplished with one view, I just need a way not to render the node title. Tips on that?

Comment: You can use the [Exclude Node Title module](https://www.drupal.org/project/exclude_node_title) to hide the page title, or do it yourself with [template_preprocess_page()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/7.x). I think the combination of a custom view block and the Exclude Node Title module is a good one. It's easy to implement, understand, document, and maintain.

Comment: @runswithscissors – You should drop a proper answer.

Comment: Since my current prefix is already tied into the title, it is easier to just remove `<h1><?php print $title; ?></h1>` from the page--MY-NODE.tpl files, and use the block view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is what I did, in case anyone wants to accomplish the something similar.

You first have to add a new region just above the content region in your `MY_THEME.info` file which in my case was:

```
regions[manufacturer_prefix_title]    = Manufacturer Prefix Title
```

Then I overwrote the `page.tpl.php` which contained:

```
  <?php if ($title): ?>
    <h1><?php print $title; ?></h1>
  <?php endif; ?>
```

to each node instance I needed `page--MY-NODE.tpl.php` which now contains:

```
  <?php if ($title): ?>
    <?php print render($page['manufacturer_prefix_title']); ?>
  <?php endif; ?>
```

(The above required a [preprocess_page hook](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/theming/template-theme-hook-suggestions#s-page-frontinternalpathtplphp).)

Then I created a block view, with the **contextual filter** set to `NID`. I also added **filter criteria** to get only the desired content types.

I added the 3 Content: Manufacturer fields, ticked `exclude from display` on each, and ticked `rewrite the output of this field` on each so that I could use the **replacement pattern** for those fields and wrap each one in the `span class` I wanted:

`<span class="MY-CLASS">[field_MY_FIELD]</span>`.

I also made sure to tick `hide if empty` under **no results behavior** so that the span class would not get rendered when the field was empty, as these fields  are not required.

I then added the Content: Title field once, and ticked `rewrite the output of this field`  and used replacement patterns for each of the manufacturer fields, leaving one space in front of the title:

```
[field_MY_FIELD_1][field_MY_FIELD_2][field_MY_FIELD_3] [title]
```

Since the **contextual filter** was set to `NID`, the title will only grab the appropriate taxonomy reference field, as only one is allowed per node.

Then all that was left was to simply place the new view block @`admin/structure/block` into the new region that was created in the `MY_THEME.info` file. I also configured the block to only show on the same content types that i defined in the **filter criteria** of the block view.

Hope this helps someone! :)